# How to call definition of different repo after release definition which is in different repo in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have one deploy job (release definition) in abc repo in 123 branch and another build job( Build definition) in def repo in 456 branch.I want to run the build job after the deploy job. I have both jobs definitions in different repo's in VSTS.What plugin I need in VSTS to call and how to accomplish this.Please help anybody.So once the release job triggers into Dev environment I should call build job which is in different repo in VSTS.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a **PowerShell task** or a related **extension task** in the end of the Dev release environment to call a build.

#### Option 1: add a PowerShell task in the end of Dev release environment

The powershell script to queue a build as below (the build definition id is 5 in below example):

```
$body = @{
definition = @{
id = 5
}
}
$Uri = "http://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0"
$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body)
```

#### Option 2: use relate task in marketplace

You can install [Queue Build(s) Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jb.queue-build) or [Queue New Build task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=delegen.DelegenQueueNewBuild) etc. And then add the task in the end of your Dev release environment.

---

#### Update: To create a release by powershell, you can use below script:

```
$body = '
{
    "definitionId": releasedefinitionID,
     "artifacts": [
        {

      "alias": "build_definition_name",
      "instanceReference": {
        "id": "buildID",
        "name": null
      }

        }
    ]
}
'
$bodyJson=$body | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output $bodyJson
$bodyString=$bodyJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
Write-Output $bodyString
$user="name"
$token="PAT"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$Uri = "https://account.vsrm.visualstudio.com/project/_apis/Release/releases?api-version=4.0-preview.4"
$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body $bodyString -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
write-host $buildresponse
```

Comment: Hi Marina, What is meant by ID over there in your script and what is the URl indicates.Could you please give me clarity so that I will use the script.I want to run the build job->release job from abc repo and upon completion on release job in abc repo I need to call another build or release job from another def repo.So how to accomplish this task.Kindly help me.This is my VSTS URL :https://telematicsapps.visualstudio.com ..So please share me the script accordingly as I am new to VSTS that's why asking.Please explain what is ID in my script and what ID I should give and what URL I should give.

Comment: And If I want to call release definition in one repo after the completion of release definition in another repo.What could be the script? Please share both the scripts ASAP.

Comment: The id is the build definition id. The shell script is based on queue build rest api, you can have a further understanding here https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build. To add a release, you can refer create a release rest api https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#create-a-release.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure the script. Can you please share me the exact script which I can include in my power shell task. I just need to call another release def which is in def repo after the release definition in abc repo.i am new to this so asking you. Please provide the power shell script to call release def which is in different repo from my current repo

Comment: Even I shared my vsts repo protect URL in the above comment

Comment: So accordingly you can share the script please

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN I added an example powershell script to create a release, you can have a try.

Comment: I would like to call build definition after the release definition.Please share me the script.FYI,Both definitions are in different branches.

Comment: The script which you have shared it for calling release definition after build definition.But I need to call build definition after release definition.Kindly share that script.earlier script which you shared is not triggering the build definition.So kindly update me the script.By the way, I don't want to create any definition ,Just want to call the already existing definition which is there is VSTS.

Comment: For how to call the build definition is already shows in the initial answer.

Comment: But that script which you provided is not triggering the build definition after the release definition.